# OS X arch command incorrect

Tags: macos, cpu-architecture

I was trying to figure out what CPU architecture my MacBook has to try and figure out why NASM wasn't working with an x86_64 gcc. The arch command returned i386. However, I can run i386 and x86_64 binaries, and according to System Info, I have a 64-bit CPU (Intel i7). Not only that, but when I run lipo -info on /usr/bin/arch, it says that it is a fat file with i386 and x86_64 architectures. If I'm not running an i386 system, why does arch say that I am?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's just the way `arch` works on OS X.  With current OS X systems, `arch` reports `i386` for Intel architectures that are capable of running 32-bit; it doesn't tell you whether they can run 64-bit or not.  The behavior appears to be a legacy of when `arch` was used to distinguish between `ppc` and `i386` platforms when Intel support was first introduced in OS X.  From the command line, more detailed information is available with `system_profiler`;  see `man 8 system_profiler` for more details.